# how to get foldername and filename using regex

Tags: php

i have output from string

```
foldername/subfolder/filename.jpg
```

how to get only `foldername/subfolder/` and only `filename.jpg`

```
$filepath = 'foldername/subfolder/filename.jpg';

$folder= (preg_match('~[^A-Za-z0-9_\./\]~', $filepath));
echo 'folder:' .'<br>' .$folder;

$filename =(preg_match('....', $filepath));

echo 'fileneme' .'<br>' .$filename;
```

output

```
folder:
foldername/subfolder/

filename:
filename.jpg
```

thank you

Comment: Forget regexes, just use `pathinfo()`.

Comment: why using regexes ? you can use `substr()` and `strrpos()` OR `pathinfo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$filepath  = 'foldername/subfolder/filename.jpg';
// using regex
$parts = preg_split('~/(?=[^/]*$)~', $filepath );
echo " folder::".$parts[0]." AND fileneme:". $parts[1];
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/663789)**

Or use **[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)**

```
$filepath  = 'foldername/subfolder/filename.jpg';
$path_parts = pathinfo($filepath);    
echo "dirname   : ".$path_parts['dirname']."\n";
echo "basename  : ".$path_parts['basename']."\n";
echo "extension : ".$path_parts['extension']."\n";
echo "filename  : ".$path_parts['filename']."\n";
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/663801)**